# Grouping and counting to get a closerate

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, counting

I want to count per `country` the number of times the `status` is `open` and the number of times the `status` is `closed`. Then calculate the `closerate` per `country`.

Data:

```
customer <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
country <- c('BE', 'NL', 'NL','NL','BE','NL','BE','BE','NL')
closeday <- c('2017-08-23', '2017-08-05', '2017-08-22', '2017-08-26', 
'2017-08-25', '2017-08-13', '2017-08-30', '2017-08-05', '2017-08-23')
closeday <- as.Date(closeday)

df <- data.frame(customer,country,closeday)
```

Adding `status`:

```
df$status <- ifelse(df$closeday < '2017-08-20', 'open', 'closed') 

  customer country   closeday status
1        1      BE 2017-08-23 closed
2        2      NL 2017-08-05   open
3        3      NL 2017-08-22 closed
4        4      NL 2017-08-26 closed
5        5      BE 2017-08-25 closed
6        6      NL 2017-08-13   open
7        7      BE 2017-08-30 closed
8        8      BE 2017-08-05   open
9        9      NL 2017-08-23 closed
```

Calculation `closerate`

```
closerate <- length(which(df$status == 'closed')) / 
(length(which(df$status == 'closed')) + length(which(df$status == 'open')))

[1] 0.6666667
```

Obviously, this is the `closerate` for the total. The challenge is to get the `closerate` per `country`. I tried adding the `closerate` calculation to `df` by:

```
df$closerate <- length(which(df$status == 'closed')) / 
(length(which(df$status == 'closed')) + length(which(df$status == 'open')))
```

But it gives all lines a `closerate` of 0.66 because I'm not grouping. I believe I should not use the length function because counting can be done by grouping. I read some information about using `dplyr` to count logical outputs per group but this didn't work out.

This is the desired output:

[image: Grouped by country]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
aggregate(list(output = df$status == "closed"),
          list(country = df$country),
          function(x)
              c(close = sum(x),
                open = length(x) - sum(x),
                rate = mean(x)))
#  country output.close output.open output.rate
#1      BE         3.00        1.00        0.75
#2      NL         3.00        2.00        0.60
```

---

There was a solution using `table` in the comments which appears to have been deleted. Anyway, you could also use `table`

```
output = as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$country, df$status))
output$closerate = output$closed/(output$closed + output$open)
output
#   closed open closerate
#BE      3    1      0.75
#NL      3    2      0.60
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tapply`:

```
data.frame(open=tapply(df$status=="open", df$country, sum),
           closed=tapply(df$status=="closed", df$country, sum)
           closerate=tapply(df$status=="closed", df$country, mean))`
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies, very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` method would be.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, {temp <- status=="closed"; # store temporary logical variable
            .(closed=sum(temp), open=sum(!temp), closeRate=mean(temp))}, # calculate stuff
          by=country] # by country
```

which returns

```
   country closed open closeRate
1:      BE      3    1      0.75
2:      NL      3    2      0.60
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
output <- df %>%
  count(country, status) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/total)
```

Returns...

```
output
country status   n total percent
BE      closed   3  4    0.75
BE      open     1  4    0.25
NL      closed   3  5    0.60
NL      open     2  5    0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution with `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(status =ifelse(closeday < '2017-08-20', 'open', 'closed'),
         closerate=mean(status=="closed"))
```

Returning:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   country [2]
  customer country   closeday status closerate
     <dbl>  <fctr>     <date>  <chr>     <dbl>
1        1      BE 2017-08-23 closed      0.75
2        2      NL 2017-08-05   open      0.60
3        3      NL 2017-08-22 closed      0.60
4        4      NL 2017-08-26 closed      0.60
5        5      BE 2017-08-25 closed      0.75
6        6      NL 2017-08-13   open      0.60
7        7      BE 2017-08-30 closed      0.75
8        8      BE 2017-08-05   open      0.75
9        9      NL 2017-08-23 closed      0.60
```

Here I am utilizing the coercion of logicals into integer when the vector of TRUE/FALSE is put into the `mean()` function.

Alternatively, with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,status:=ifelse(closeday < '2017-08-20', 'open', 'closed')]
df[, .(closerate=mean(status=="closed")), by=country]
```