# Grouping and counting to get ratios in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here's another [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083507/grouping-and-counting-to-get-a-closerate) on dataframes asked in the [r](/questions/tagged/r) that would benefit from a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) solution. Here's the question.

> I want to count per `country` the number of times the `status` is
>   `open` and the number of times the `status` is `closed`. Then
>   calculate the `closerate` per `country`.
>
> Data:
>
> ```
>   customer country   closeday status
> 1        1      BE 2017-08-23 closed
> 2        2      NL 2017-08-05   open
> 3        3      NL 2017-08-22 closed
> 4        4      NL 2017-08-26 closed
> 5        5      BE 2017-08-25 closed
> 6        6      NL 2017-08-13   open
> 7        7      BE 2017-08-30 closed
> 8        8      BE 2017-08-05   open
> 9        9      NL 2017-08-23 closed
> ```
>
> The idea is to get an output depicting the number of `open` and
>   `closed` status, and the `close_ratio`. This is the desired output:
>
> ```
> country   closed  open  closed_ratio                         
> BE            3     1          0.75
> NL            3     2          0.60
> ```
>
> Look forward to your suggestions.

Solution included below in an answer. Welcome other solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's are some ways

**1)**

```
In [420]: (df.groupby(['country', 'status']).size().unstack()
             .assign(closed_ratio=lambda x: x.closed / x.sum(1)))
Out[420]:
status   closed  open  closed_ratio
country
BE            3     1          0.75
NL            3     2          0.60
```

**2)**

```
In [422]: (pd.crosstab(df.country, df.status)
             .assign(closed_ratio=lambda x: x.closed/x.sum(1)))
Out[422]:
status   closed  open  closed_ratio
country
BE            3     1          0.75
NL            3     2          0.60
```

**3)**

```
In [424]: (df.pivot_table(index='country', columns='status', aggfunc='size')
             .assign(closed_ratio=lambda x: x.closed/x.sum(1)))
Out[424]:
status   closed  open  closed_ratio
country
BE            3     1          0.75
NL            3     2          0.60
```

**4)** borrowed from piRSquared

```
In [430]: (df.set_index('country').status.str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
             .assign(closed_ratio=lambda x: x.closed/x.sum(1)))
Out[430]:
         closed  open  closed_ratio
country
BE            3     1          0.75
NL            3     2          0.60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df

   customer country    closeday  status
1         1      BE  2017-08-23  closed
2         2      NL  2017-08-05    open
3         3      NL  2017-08-22  closed
4         4      NL  2017-08-26  closed
5         5      BE  2017-08-25  closed
6         6      NL  2017-08-13    open
7         7      BE  2017-08-30  closed
8         8      BE  2017-08-05    open
9         9      NL  2017-08-23  closed
```

---

Apply the `groupby`, and count each group with `size`, and then `unstack` the first level.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['country', 'status']).status.size().unstack(level=1)
df2

status   closed  open
country              
BE            3     1
NL            3     2
```

Now, calculate `closed_ratio`:

```
df2['closed_ratio'] = df2.closed / df2.sum(1)     
df2

status   closed  open  closed_ratio
country                            
BE            3     1          0.75
NL            3     2          0.60
```